# Query to get recent messages in a 'threaded' view

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to rebuild an existing messaging system so it looks similar to Twitter's DM service. Currently I am only showing unread messages to my users, but I would like to show messages sent between 2 users in a single 'thread' like this:

[image]

Here is my current database structure and some sample data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/574e3/1/0

I've tried building the query step by step by breaking it down, but I'm confused. 
This is a list of the steps that I have taken:

**1. Get a list of messages sent between two users**

```
SELECT * FROM uc_user_messages
WHERE uc_user_messages.user_id_1 = 1 OR uc_user_messages.user_id_2 = 1
```

**2. Show the last message in the 'conversation' between two users**

```
SELECT * FROM uc_user_messages
WHERE uc_user_messages.user_id_1 = 1 OR uc_user_messages.user_id_2 = 1
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

**3. Group the conversation by user_id (obviously this would be a user's name with a bunch of joins in a production application).**

```
SELECT * FROM uc_user_messages
WHERE uc_user_messages.user_id_1 = 1 OR uc_user_messages.user_id_2 = 1
GROUP BY uc_user_messages.user_id_1 AND uc_user_messages.user_id_2
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

And this is where I'm stuck... The problem is that the first message sent in a conversation between two users will be shown, instead of the most recent message: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/942fb/2

What can I do about this? Hopefully I won't have to make any major database design changes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Joel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    uc_user_messages
WHERE   (LEAST(user_id_1, user_id_2),GREATEST(user_id_1, user_id_2),TIMESTAMP) 
        IN 
        (
            SELECT  LEAST(user_id_1, user_id_2) AS x,
                    GREATEST(user_id_1, user_id_2) AS y,
                    max(TIMESTAMP) AS msg_time
            FROM    uc_user_messages
            GROUP   BY x, y
        );
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/942fb/8)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════╦════════════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ USER_ID_1 ║ USER_ID_2 ║     MESSAGE     ║ TIMESTAMP  ║ READ ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════╬════════════╬══════╣
║  3 ║         1 ║         2 ║ third message   ║ 1366577336 ║    1 ║
║  4 ║         2 ║         0 ║ a message reply ║ 1366577346 ║    1 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════╩════════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but the OP seemed interested in messages involving user_id number 1. So how is that last message ("a message reply") relevant?

Comment: @JamesHolderness you're not misundertanding it. It just that I have no  additional condition to filter for a specific `User_ID`. The query above will show the most recent message for all conversation of multiple user. A simple `AND 1 IN (USER_ID_1, USER_ID_2)` will only give result for conversation containing `user_id = 1` [here's a DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/942fb/24)

Comment: Wow! I would have never had thought of this. I actually only just noticed that there was a typo in record 4, so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have been testing the query for the past few minutes and it seems to work very well. I've added AND USER_ID_1 != USER_ID_2 to the end of the query so users don't see two threads of their own message (if they're silly enough to send their selves a message in the first place!). Thank you for your help @JW웃 :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, and you're looking for the most recent message between users 1 and 2, then this is one way to do it.

```
SELECT * FROM uc_user_messages
WHERE id = (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM uc_user_messages
  WHERE uc_user_messages.user_id_1 = 1 OR uc_user_messages.user_id_2 = 1
)
```

This relies on the `id` being ascending though, which may not be a great idea. An alternative would be to use the `timestamp`, but that would only work if it could be guaranteed to be unique for those users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the other response seems more well suited towards my needs as I need to get a list of all messages between users, not just 2 single users.

Comment: No problem. I agree the other answer is much better.